# What does the XML and HTML parser option, NONET = 2048, do or mean?

Tags: xml-parsing, crystal-lang

In the Crystal standard library, the [HTML](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/xml/htmlparseroptions) and [XML](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.23.0/xml/parseroptions) parser options both have `NONET`. What does this option do to modify `XML.parse`/`XML.parse_html` parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It disables any network connections while parsing, for example connecting to the internet to retrieve XML DTDs.